# How to Generate Random Year in Python with format YYYY?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code to generate fake name, age, address, I want to know what is the line to generate fake year in YYYY format?

```
def create_fake_users(n):
    """Generate fake users."""
    faker = Faker()
    for i in range(n):
        user = User(name=faker.name(),
                    age=random.randint(20, 80),
                    address=faker.address().replace('\n', ', '),
                    phone=faker.phone_number(),
                    email=faker.email())
        db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    print(f'Added {n} fake users to the database.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, this works for your solution

```
from faker import Faker
import datetime
fake = Faker()
date = fake.date()
datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
datetime_object.year
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use faker to generate random dates as well:

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

#one hundred years from today
fake.date_between(start_date='today', end_date='+100y')
#datetime.date(2038, 5, 10)

# last one hundred years
fake.date_time_between(start_date='-100y', end_date='now')
#datetime.datetime(1989, 10, 7, 19, 47, 27)
```

If you just want the year in `YYYY` then:

```
fake.date_between(start_date='today', end_date='+100y').year
#2038

fake.date_time_between(start_date='-100y', end_date='now').year
#1989
```